# Is a section of Prelude from the JSB Partita No. 3 for Violin Solo (BWV 1006) commonly repeated or missing from the score?

Tags: classical-music

I am trying to learn this solo, but to better my sounds, I am trying to play along to a recording once I get it down with a metronome. IN measure 58 there seems to be a repeat, however, in every performance I can find that isn't in the score. That or they are playing a totally different part not in the score.

This score is exactly the same as what I have in my book of classical tunes.
https://musescore.com/user/27667841/scores/6551312

Here is an example of someone playing this extra section.

Comment: That score doesn't absolutely seem very reliable, it's probably just a "simplified" version. There's nothing "repeated", it's missing more than half of that prelude, and that's a lot of very important stuff too. Why don't you check it on [imslp.org](https://imslp.org/wiki/6_Violin_Sonatas_and_Partitas,_BWV_1001-1006_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian)), for example?

Comment: Actually, even between those printed versions there are some drastic differences in the second half, but this seems to be what I hear most often. https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/6/6e/IMSLP250590-SIBLEY1802.21004.93cd-39087009905870score.pdf

Comment: What drasticly different versions are you referring to?

Comment: Look at this version (page 47):

https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/b/b4/IMSLP237324-SIBLEY1802.15620.895b-39087009905888score.pdf

Comment: Measures 55-123 are the missing ones from this "simplified" version.

Comment: The last version you linked is actually missing 2 *pages* of the book... That's not a "version" problem, but a scanning one.

Comment: @musicamante It would be helpful to turn these comments into an answer so that users can see that it has one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As many examples can be seen in various *reliable* editions of the piece (for example, at [imslp](https://imslp.org/wiki/6_Violin_Sonatas_and_Partitas,_BWV_1001-1006_(Bach,_Johann_Sebastian))), the only actual differences are mostly ornaments, writing of voices, technique markings and slurs, stems/flags/groupings and some dynamics, while the structure remains intact as it can be listened in the embedded video as well as thousands of other audio/video sources around the web.

The score reported in the link is a shortened version, probably intended for beginners.

<sup>On a personal note, I don't really see the point in skipping so much important material, as more than half of the piece is missing, the missing parts are not *that* difficult compared to what's left (and they are very important for its structure too): it *is* a difficult piece, there's no benefit in shortening to make it "easier", if the result completely denaturalize it.</sup>

Comment: I think the purpose of doing so in the book I was using is that it is a classical fakebook, and they want things to fit on 1-2 pages where possible. In that sense, It's a cool survey of the styles, but now I know that if I like a piece I will need to get the original. It's a cool way to work on sight reading and learn about composer's styles, without having to invest too much time into a piece you may not like.

Comment: @bartcubrich I see your point, but I still believe it's not a very good practice: as said, that's not an easy piece, and if you're going to play it (at least on the violin) you probably already know that style. Also, a "fakebook" would make sense for excerpts, short melodies, more or less as they do with common themes with children methods (the usual "Ode to Joy", for instance). With a piece like this, you've already got to almost half of it, "cutting" it down, especially like that, is just a pity (some would say it's a shame).